How to determine what region two inequalities satisfy?
What region on a coordinate grid would satisfies these inequalites:

$$y > (3-x)(2+x) \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; y + x ≥ 3$$

The answer in my textbook shows the correct answer is as follows

however I was skeptical as to whether this is accurate as when you insert coordinates in the shaded region such as $(0,4)$ it satisfies the linear inequality but not the quadratic.

I don't understand what's wrong with this question. It looks perfectly fine to me, maybe simple for many of the user but well posed and presented.

Note that
$$y=(3-x)(2+x)=-x^2+x+6$$
is indeed an downward parabola and you are right to be skeptical  indeed the shaded area in the textbook would require the reversed inequality
$$y\color{red}<(3-x)(2+x)$$
Here below a sketch with the two cases


Should have $-x^2 \color{red}{+ x} + 6$$

@MPW Very good cacth! Thanks
